# Application using Node js, express js and mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, express

Anybody working example using node js, express js and mongo db? I have tried many links and most of them are raising errors.

The application must involve insert, update, delete, select operations of database.

Comment: Here is the Live App I built http://nodejs-crud.herokuapp.com/ and the tutorial link is http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/crud-operations-in-node-js-and-mongodb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atlast I got one example working fine for me. Giving the link below. Hope this helps you:

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

Following helped me:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Its an ecomm app with CRUD operations.